# The difference between "-D" and "&" in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh

According to this  [docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

What's the difference between

```
./my_first_process -D
```

`./my_main_process &`

They both seem unblocking to bash script and run in background

Comment: Sounds like your `my_first_process` treats `-D` as an instruction to self-demonize. That's behavior specific to that individual program, not something generally true.

Comment: ...that said, self-daemonization is not a particularly good habit to be in; it's harder for a process supervision system to monitor a server that behaves that way. Certainly do keep it as an option rather than a default, if the program is one you control.

Comment: BTW, that tutorial is showcasing several bad practices. See f/e [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313216/14122)

Answer (score 3):

`&` tells the shell to put the command that precedes it into the background. `-D` is simply a flag that is passed to `my_first_process` and is interpreted by it; it has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the shell.

You will have to look into the documentation of `my_first_process` to see what `-D` does … it could mean anything. E.g. in `npm`, `-D` means "development", whereas in some other tools, it may mean "directory". In `diff`, it means "Output merged file to show `#ifdef NAME' diffs."

Answer (score 1):

*Some* programs, by convention, take `-D` as an instruction to *self-daemonize*. Doing this looks something like the following:

- Call `fork()`, and exit if it returns 0 (so only the child survives).
- Close stdin, stdout and stderr if they are attached to the console (ideally, replacing their file descriptors with handles on `/dev/null`, so writes don't trigger an error).
- Call `setsid()` to create a new session.
- Call `fork()` again, and exit if it returns 0 again.

That's a lot more work than what just `someprogram &` does! A program that has self-daemonized can no longer log to the terminal, and will no longer be impacted if the terminal itself closes. That's not true of a program that's just started in the background.

To get something similar to the same behavior from bash, correct code would be something like:

```
someprogram </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown -h
```

...wherein `disown -h` tells the shell not to pass along a SIGHUP to that process. It's also not uncommon to see the external tool `nohup` used for this purpose (though by default, it redirects stdout and stderr to a file called `nohup.out` if they're pointed at the TTY, the end purpose -- of making sure they're *not* pointed at the terminal, and thus that writes to them don't start failing if the terminal goes away -- is achieved):

```
nohup someprogram >/dev/null &
```